# How to access cookie asp.net core

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, httpcontext

```
var claims = new[]
{
  new Claim("UserID", user.ID.ToString()),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "pioneer")
};

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                  new ClaimsIdentity(
                    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", principal);
```

This is the cookie that I'm creating and using to sign in as per instruction from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie

The cookie is being created, but I don't know how to access the cookie or the data inside of it to get the user.ID value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you sign via `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync`, you should be able to access the `User` property in your controllers (it is part of `ControllerBase`), or `HttpContext.User`.

This `User` is a `ClaimsPrincipal` object that is created from the cookie automatically.